# Nativescript: How to position an element in the center of the viewport, regardless of other content?

Tags: android, nativescript

I want to position an ActivityIndicator element in the center of the phone(both vertically and horizontally). I have a page that looks something like that:

```
<Page class="page">
    <ActionBar class="action-bar">
      <Label class="action-bar-title" text="Image backup"></Label>
    </ActionBar>
    <TabView :selectedIndex="selectedIndex" @selectedIndexChange="indexChange">
      <TabViewItem title="Add images">
        <StackLayout>
          <Button @tap="takePicture" text="Take picture"></Button>...
          <StackLayout v-if="newImages.length" orientation="horizontal">...</StackLayout>
          <RadListView layout="grid" ref="newImages" for="image in newImages">
            <v-template>
              ...
            </v-template>
          </RadListView>
        </StackLayout>
      </TabViewItem>
      <TabViewItem title="Backedup images">
        <StackLayout>
          <Button @tap="fetchAllBackedupImages" text="Get all backedup images"></Button>
          <StackLayout v-if="backedupImages.length" orientation="horizontal">
            ...
          </StackLayout>
          <RadListView layout="grid" ref="backedupImages" for="image in sortedBackedupImages">
            <v-template>...</v-template>
          </RadListView>
        </StackLayout>
      </TabViewItem>
    </TabView>
  </Page>
```

All i want is to show/hide the ActivityIndicator , exactly in the middle of the page. It should be the Android equivalent of this CSS:

```
.centered {
  position: fixed;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

How can this be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just wrap the whole content with a `GridLayout` and add `ActivityIndicator` as second child on the same layout. Something like,

```
<Page class="page">
    <ActionBar class="action-bar">
        <Label class="action-bar-title" text="Image backup"></Label>
    </ActionBar>
    <GridLayout>
        <TabView :selectedIndex="selectedIndex" @selectedIndexChange="indexChange">
            <TabViewItem title="Add images">
                <StackLayout>
                    <Button @tap="takePicture" text="Take picture"></Button>...
                    <StackLayout v-if="newImages.length" orientation="horizontal">...</StackLayout>
                    <RadListView layout="grid" ref="newImages" for="image in newImages">
                        <v-template>
                            ...
                        </v-template>
                    </RadListView>
                </StackLayout>
            </TabViewItem>
            <TabViewItem title="Backedup images">
                <StackLayout>
                    <Button @tap="fetchAllBackedupImages" text="Get all backedup images"></Button>
                    <StackLayout v-if="backedupImages.length" orientation="horizontal">
                        ...
                    </StackLayout>
                    <RadListView layout="grid" ref="backedupImages" for="image in sortedBackedupImages">
                        <v-template>...</v-template>
                    </RadListView>
                </StackLayout>
            </TabViewItem>
        </TabView>
        <ActivityIndicator></ActivityIndicator>
    </GridLayout>
</Page>
```

Then you could simply toggle the `busy` attribute whenever you want to show / hide indicator. If adding `ActivityIndicator` to every `Page` is too much, then you could wrap your root Frame with `GridLayout` and similarly add `ActivityIndicator` there, so you will not have to add it on every `Page`.

While this approach works, I would recommend using a progress dialog instead, so you can actually block user from accessing the UI if you like to, Here is  [Playground Sample](https://play.nativescript.org/?template=play-tsc&id=mG98x6&v=1) for similar approach.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I used the playground, and it looks very nice. I see that ProgressDialog api was deprecated: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ProgressDialog . Also, in Tns-Vue i see only a component called simply Progress, which seems a bit different. Can something similar be achieved with it?

Comment: The alternative is using `ActivityIndicator` only, Android seems to prefer not blocking the UI with latest versions. iOS has an option to disable any events on UI without blocking with modal dialog which is not available in Android, so I prefer ProgressDialog to prevent user interaction.

Comment: I see, this is what i will do. I have another problem though: i need to keep two separate activity indicators, one for each tab. I do not want to show the loader on both "pages"(tabs), when an ajax(for example) is being awaited that is relevant to only one of them. I tried placing this GridLayout inside a TabViewItem, and it basically "kills" the contents. Can you point me to the right direction here?

Comment: You may use GridLayout inside TabViewItem, I'm not sure how you did it, may be you missed something in your code.

Comment: Yes sorry, i had some CSS interfering. Thank you for your help as always!